# Using Google GSI Client does not work. It does not redirect the user to the landing page

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-signin

I'm trying to use Google GSI Client so users can sign in using Google account. The process is this:

1. User click the Google Sign In Button.
2. User will choose Google Account.
3. After choosing, the server PHP file will check the email if its already in the database.
4. If true, redirect to landing page.

I have 3 files named:

- login.php (where the Google Sign In is located),
- handle_google_signin.php (where the server checks the email if already exist),
- index.php (the landing page).

I search the web for codes for GSI, as well as the javascript for that.But when I tried to sign in using Google, it only stucks on /handle_google_signin.php instead of redirecting to landing page.

I already have the client ID and put the redirect URI and the JS Origin on the console cloud. Also, the website where I will implement this GSI is in the https already.

Here is the code for html:

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="CLIENT ID"
     data-callback="onSignIn"
     data-auto_prompt="false"
     data-ux_mode="redirect"
     data-login_uri="https://ceit.rf.gd/handle_google_signin.php">
</div>
<div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard"></div>
```

js:

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    var id = profile.getId();
    var name = profile.getName();
    var email = profile.getEmail();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'handle_google_signin.php', 
        data: { id: id, name: name, email: email },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response === 'success') {
                window.location.href = 'index.php'; 
            } else {
                console.error('Error:', response);
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        }
    });
}
```

php:

```
<?php
require('connect.php');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Retrieve user details from the POST request
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    
    // Log the email address to the PHP error log
    error_log('Received email: ' . $email);
    // Perform a database check to see if the email exists
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tblAccount WHERE email = '$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // Email exists in the database
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        echo 'success'; // Indicate successful sign-in
    } else {
        // Email does not exist in the database
        echo 'Email not found in the database.';
        // Perform other actions or return an error message as needed
    }
}
?>
```

Looking forward to your insights.

Comment: Use console.log(response) right before the if statement in the success callback of your AJAX request to debug what the actual server response is.

Comment: still the console does not show response

Comment: just to do a test, try change it $query = "SELECT * FROM tblAccount WHERE email = '$email'";    for it  $query = "SELECT * FROM tblAccount WHERE email = '".$email."'";

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is just a insight!

Lets try it:
Sometimes, the response from the server may contain additional data or whitespace. Trim the response before checking its value.

```
success: function(response) {
    var trimmedResponse = response.trim();
    if (trimmedResponse === 'success') {
         console.error('Success:', trimmedResponse);
        //window.location.href = 'index.php'; // after remove the comment to this line
    } else {
        console.error('Error:', trimmedResponse);
    }
},
```

Ensure that you start the session at the beginning of your PHP script:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Add that at the top of your code
require('connect.php');
// ... rest of your code
```

Do this tests to be sure the response is really working:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {         
   // Email exists in the database         
   $_SESSION['email'] = $email;            
   echo 'success'; // Indicate successful sign-in         
   exit;     
} else {         
   // Email does not exist in the database         
   echo 'Email not found in the database.';         
   // Perform other actions or return an error message as needed
  exit;     
}
```

So this a debug idea, do not keep the exit in your code after;
Try other things like add the $email value in the exit value to be sure if the variable has value,  after remove it.